# Forward stepwise AIC approach

Tags: feature-selection, aic, stepwise-regression

I am learning about performing stepwise model selection by AIC and I have 2 questions here:

1.Regarding to stepwise AIC, what is contribution (effectiveness) of the number of parameters in the model to optimize the model fit?

2.For **forward** stepwise AIC approach, what would be an advantage and disadvantage of fixing previously estimated coefficients (using them as an offset)?

Comment: Your questions are quite distinct, so it would make sense to split them into two separate threads (and add more informative titles). Here is an answer to the first one: 1. The more parameters, the more flexible the model, the better in-sample fit. Out-of-sample fit may be either better or worse. This holds not only for stepwise regression but also more generally.